# calculate the difference between two UTC times in hours C#

Tags: c#, utc

How do I calculate the difference between two UTC times in hours?

This is what I have tried:

```
// var lastSuccessfulRunTime = 2023-01-01T00:00:00Z UTC Time
int timeDifference = (DateTime.UtcNow - lastSuccessfulRunTime).Hours
```

if (DateTime.UtcNow - lastSuccessfulRunTime) = 9.00:00:00.7944388, timeDifference will be 0 which is not what I need.

Comment: what about `TotalHours`?

Comment: what do you want the answer to be in that case?

Comment: I'll be honest, I'm not sure what you mean by your second sentence, but my answer answers your first sentence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Hours` property returns the integer hours value of the timespace.

i.e. for an hour and a half, it would give you 1.

The `TotalHours` property, converts the entire timespan into the `double` representation.

i.e. for an hour and a half, it would give you 1.5

You want:

`double timeDifference = (DateTime.UtcNow - lastSuccessfulRunTime).TotalHours`

(note, your int variable type is also wrong)

This applies to all of the time-component properties on a `DateTime`